# Accessing SFTP folders transparently in Explorer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, sftp

One feature available on Linux (using Nautilus from Gnome) that I really like a lot is the ability to access remote servers via SFTP just by typing `sftp://server/folder` and saving those as bookmarks.

Until now I used WinSCP for accessing SFTP folders on Windows, but after using Linux for a while I find it a bit inconvenient and I am looking for an easier, better integrated way of accessing SFTP folders.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality in Windows 7? I'd like to transparently access remote folders via SFTP in the Windows Explorer as if they were SMB shares or local folders.

Comment: So far I found a lot of applications that can do the transparent stuff / backup there / whatsoever, HOWEVER they are not free or open-source at all. :)

Comment: Excuse me, there is ONE, but I couldn't get it work: http://www.swish-sftp.org/

Answer (score 2):

[ExpanDrive](http://www.expandrive.com/) can do this also.

> ExpanDrive acts just like a USB drive plugged into your computer. Open, edit, and save files to remote computers from within your favorite programs—even when they are on a server half a world away. ExpanDrive enhances every single application on your computer by transparently connecting it to remote data

Answer (score 2):

Try Swish here: http://swish-sftp.org

It helps if you already have some PuTTY keys created.  Swish uses a component of PuTTY called Pageant which acts as a keystore.

Answer (score 0):

[Dokan SSHFS](http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/) doesn't provide `sftp://` support like gvfs, but at least it allows mapping SFTP connections to network drives.